# How do I cast JPA criteria Expression<Long> to long java type

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

This code

```
    criteriaBuilder.literal(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays( (long) root.get("person").get("birthDay").as(Long.class)))
```

has not compile error but at run time gets this error:
Cannot cast from Expression to int

I tried using String:

```
    criteriaBuilder.literal(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays( Long.parseValue( root.get("person").get("birthDay").toString())))
```

This also gets error:
ERROR: For input string: "org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath@2ed2d35d"; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath@2ed2d35d"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first error, you are mixing `LocalDateTime.now().minusDays` with the `Expression` `root.get("person").get("birthDay").as(Long.class)`, and it is not possible.

The error is not detected at compile time because you are actually casting the `Expression` `root.get("person").get("birthDay").as(Long.class)` to `long`:

```java
(long) root.get("person").get("birthDay").as(Long.class)
```

So everything is fine for the compiler, but at runtime an error will be raised because an `Expression` is not a `long` value.

In your second error you are trying using:

```java
root.get("person").get("birthDay").toString()
```

As a result of the evaluation of this code you will get a `String` representation of the JPA criteria path you are defining, `org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath@2ed2d35d` in your use case.

Then, if you compute `Long.parseValue` of `org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath@2ed2d35d` if will raise an error because `org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath@2ed2d35d` doesn't represent a valid number.

Under the hood, the problem is that you are trying to apply the operation `LocalDateTime.now().minusDays` to an `Expression`, but it is not possible, you need to perform the computation in some other suitable way.

It is unclear by your question what you are actually trying to achieve, but the JPA criteria API provides a rich set of builtin expressions you can use as `Predicate`s to deal with dates, such as, assuming `root.get("person").get("birthDay")` represent a `Date` *like* object:

```java
cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("person").get("birthDay"), cb.literal(LocalDate.now()));
//...
cb.greaterThan(root.get("person").get("birthDay"), cb.literal(LocalDate.now()));
//...
cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("person").get("birthDay"), cb.literal(LocalDate.now()));
//...
cb.lessThan(root.get("person").get("birthDay"), cb.literal(LocalDate.now()));
```

You can create your own function using `cb.function` as well and use that function in your predicates. Consider for that purpose defining a helper method somewhere in your code, for example:

```java
public static Expression<Long> daysBetween(
  CriteriaBuilder cb, Expression<LocalDate> startDate, Expression<LocalDate> endDate) {
  return cb.function("DAYS_BETWEEN", long.class, startDate, endDate);
}
```

Where `DAYS_BETWEEN` is the name, you can choose the one you consider most appropriate, of a database level predefined or user defined function. In Oracle for example it exists *per se*, but it should be straight forward to implement in other database systems:

```sql
create or replace function days_between...
```

Then, use this helper method in your code. For example, *give me the persons that turns years in the following `numberOfDaysToTurnYears` days*:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
 
CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);

Root<Person> root = query.from(Person.class);

ParameterExpression<Integer> numberOfDaysToTurnYears = cb.parameter(Integer.class);

query.where(
  cb.lessThan(
    // Here you can use LocalDate.now(), because it is actually a pure literal value
    daysBetween(cb, root.get("person").get("birthDay"), cb.literal(LocalDate.now())),
    numberOfDaysToTurnYears
  )
);

List<Person> people = entityManager.createQuery(query)
    .setParameter(numberOfDaysToTurnYears, 10)
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: @Shadyar Were you able to test any of the provided solutions? Please, could you further elaborate your question in order to trying helping you? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this, I found the relevant documentation, I think it seems to be available like the following, just to provide a reference, I hope it can help you.

[literal(T)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/ejb/criteria/CriteriaBuilderImpl.html#literal(T))

[image]

```
Integer a = 1;
Long b = 2L;
String c = "3";
Expression<Integer> integerParameter = criteriaBuilder.literal(a);
Expression<Long> longParameter = criteriaBuilder.literal(b);
Expression<String> stringParameter = criteriaBuilder.literal(c);
```

And i found that method [minusDays(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#minusDays-long) return a `LocalDateTime`, so i think we should take that like :

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays( (long) root.get("person").get("birthDay").as(Long.class));
Expression<LocalDateTime> longParameter = criteriaBuilder.literal(ldt);
```

As for how to convert LocalDateTime into the data you need, I am currently unclear, because it is not clear what your specific needs are.

Comment: Are you sure about this code? Have you self run this line? Code: LocalDateTime.now().minusDays( (long) root.get("person").get("birthDay").as(Long.class));    I'd written something like that but it got exception at run time.

Comment: @Shadyar the minusDays need take a long param; the code `(long) root.get("person").get("birthDay").as(Long.class)`  is from you, i dont check that ! we must give a long into minusDays! how to be a long, you should do